# Rotation of a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

Parc c of Exercise 4.3.12 in Shifrin and Adams' *Linear Algebra: a Geometric Approach* says

> Let $V \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be the subspace defined by 
>   $$V =  \{(x_1, x_2, x_3): x_1 - x_2 + x_3 =0\}.$$
>
> Find the standard matrix for rotation of $V$ through angle $\pi/6$ (as
>   viewed from high above).

What does it mean to rotate $V$ through angle $\pi/6$ (as viewed from high above)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

V is a plane, in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, so viewing this from far enough to see a rotation of an infinite thing is kind of confusing, so maybe pretend you mark a square on it with different colored sides and step back and see how the square moves after a rotation by $\pi/6$ counterclockwise.

Comment: So you're saying the rotation is about the plane's normal line?

Comment: yes I believe so